# can I auto add hash tag into URL when the site is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I would like to know if there is any possible way to re-write a URL to include a hash tag when the site load?

**Example:**
www.google.com would automatically become www.google.com#something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

```
location.hash = 'something';
```

Running this piece of code will add '#something' to the URL of said page.

Comment: Could you elaborate. How am I misunderstanding his question?

Comment: sorry can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: @Bobby Is it possible you are not asking everything you want to know?

Comment: @Bobby It is javascript. Put it inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Ok the solution given is working. Thank you for your helps and sorry if I did mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **AUTOMATICALLY** redirect from `www.google.com` to `www.google.com#something`
you can use firefox's redirector addon.
Whenever you load www.google.com, the addon will automatically change the URL in the location bar to www.google.com#something (or whatever you specify.)

Alternately, you could use firefox addon, called greasemonkey, to write the 1 line script given by Jacob. That will also serve the purpose.

Off course, both these solutions are specific to firefox.

Comment: Actually I wanna apply this to my own website. I use google for example only. Is there any programmatically way?

Comment: I am assumming that you are aware of how the #bookmarks are created in HTML. <a name="something"/> will create a bookmark.

Comment: If you want your website's users to automatically scroll to page2.html#something, you can use <a href="page2.html#something">Page2</a> from page1.html (or whatever).
Alternately, you can also use location.hash="something"; in page2.html 's javascript code. However, it will ALWAYS scroll to that bookmark, irrespective of how you reached that page.

Comment: Bobby, please could you use proper english, instead of 'wanna'

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new here. My english is not well but I will be polite.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to do it, correct me if i have mis-understood your question !
First use location.hash to add the "#something" to your URL
Then redirect to the location using window.location in javascript. 
Try this snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        location.hash = "something";
        window.location = location.hash;
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```